# Can we arbitrary get close to the supremum?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, continuity

Assume $f(t)$ is a continues function in $[0,\infty)$. We know that

$$0\leq f(t) \leq 1, \space \forall t$$.

I know $f(t)$ may not have a maximum, but can we show that for any $\epsilon>0$ there is a $t$ such that $$Sup(f)-f(t)<\epsilon$$

In words, can we show that there is a point which is arbitrary close to the supremum?

Comment: Yes. Continuity of $f$ isn't required, even.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes for if $\sup f-f(t)\geq\varepsilon$ for all $t$ then $\sup f-\varepsilon<\sup f$ is an upper bound for $f(t)$ which is a contradiction of the fact that $\sup f$ is the *least* upper bound.